# Javascript "window.top" issue in iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I have an ASP.NET website in which I embedded an iframe inside a page and open a third party website inside it, i.e. I do not have a control on that website. Now that website uses a javascript with "window.top" at many places to access elements, like:

```
window.top.$('#elementid')...
```

The problem is as the website is opened in an iframe, "top" inside third party website refers to topmost browser window which is my website page, and not their website. So it will not get elements with id it uses. And so it throws javascript errors and not loaded correctly. When I open that website in new tab, it loads correctly.

I need a solution to make "top" refer to the iframe itself or any alternative to iframe which embeds that website inside my website's page and also loads correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a suspicious thing to do, to have a third party web page inside an iframe in your page, and fool the third party web page into thinking it's not in an iframe

Comment: No its not fooling them. Third party website here is my webmail itself, i.e. my site is "example.com" and in iframe I need to open "webmail.example.com" for logged in user in my website. I cannot modify my domain's webmail javascript.

Comment: then there's nothing you can do except read the duplicate and see if it helps - you got me thinking though - it's a subdomain

Comment: thanks! yes its a subdomain but provided by domain service and I do not have its control.